# why would I not use a constructor for this struct in c++?

Tags: c++

My professor was building a class student with a list of structures that doesn't have a constructor in it. but for whatever reason said that a constructor wasn't necessary, why would that be? I have emailed him and got no response, so I was wondering if someone could tell me why it wouldn't need a constructor. Here is the struct and class

```cpp
struct Record
{
    string class_name;
    char grade;
};
class Student
{

public:
    Student(string &name);
    void printRecords();
    char gradeForClass(string &cl_name);
    string standing();
    void addClass(string&, char);

private:
    int numClassesTaken;
    string st_name;
    std::list<Records> st_records;
};
```

Comment: please properly indent and format your code. It is **unreadable**.

Comment: Fields in a struct are public by default, so the `Record` type can be meaningfully used without a custom constructor (using either initialization or later assignment to the fields). `Student` currently requires a constructor to set the name once (on creation) .. or does "constructor wasn't necessary" relate to something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about `Record` he/she is right in the sense that you can initialize a `Record` object without writing a constructor for it. `Record` is an aggregate which means you can use [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization):

```
Record r{"some class name", 'A'};
```

There are some problem though with this approach. Due to some complicated rules this:

```
Record r;
```

will leave the `r.grade` field in uninitialized state. You would need to use this instead:

```
Record r{};
```

Another option is to have a default initialization for `grade`

```
struct Record
{
    string class_name;
    char grade{}
    // or
    // char grade = 'S';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of a constructor is to set the object's state to a well-defined initial state, so that it will be ready for use after the constructor returns.

For your `struct Record` to be in a well-defined initial state, both the `class_name` and `grade` fields would need to be initialized.

`class_name` is of type `std::string`, so the `std::string` class's constructor will take care of initializing it.

`grade`, OTOH, is a primitive type that has no constructor, so unless it is explicitly initialized elsewhere, it will contain uninitialized memory after the `Record` object is created.

Therefore, I think your professor is technically right but from a design viewpoint he's wrong; a constructor for the `Record` struct would be helpful to guarantee correctness.  Without a constructor you must rely on the calling code to remember to initialize the `grade` value, which introduces the possibility of an uninitialized-memory-read bug if/when the calling code forgets to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `addClass()` is the only way to add `Record` instances into the `Student::st_records` list then technically `Record` does not need a constructor of its own, as `addClass()` can simply default-construct a new `Record` and fully populate it with values before adding it to the list, eg:

```
void Student::addClass(string &name, char grade)
{
    Record r;
    r.class_name = name;
    r.grade = grade;
    st_records.push_back(r);
}
```